# TestNG gracefully kills the thread. Any idea why?

Tags: java, testng

I'm using TestNG version `7.1.0` and this is my sample code:

```java
@Test
public void testThreads(){
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("This is printed");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("This is not printed");
    }).start();
}
```

The output here is just `This is printed` while the second line is ignored. No exception is thrown. However if I'm doing this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("This is printed");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("This is not printed");
    }).start();
}
```

Both lines are printed as expected. Can you please explain why that strange behavior is observed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestNG uses a call to `System.exit` to execute your test case. That will terminate your started thread. If you add a clearly longer wait than 100 millis at the end of your test method, after you have started the explicit thread, you will see the second print statement.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed that was the reason. Another way is using `join()` on the thread you have started.